# Join con tres tablas. No logro que haga bien las sumas

Tags: mysql, join

Join con tres tablas. No logro que haga bien las sumas.

TALBA PARTES.

- ID, FECHA, PROBLEMA, ID_CLIENTE, TECNICO, ESTADO.

TABLA PARTES_LINEAS.

- ID, ID_PARTES, HORAS.

TABLA PARTES_MATERIALES.

- ID, ID_PARTES, PV_MAT.

TABLA CLIENTES.

- ID, NOMBRE.

---

```
SELECT partes.id, partes.fecha, clientes.nombre, partes.problema, 
sum(partes_lineas.horas) as horas, 
sum(partes_materiales.pv_mat) as materiales, 
partes.estado 

FROM partes 

LEFT JOIN partes_lineas 
ON partes.id = partes_lineas.id_parte 

LEFT JOIN partes_materiales 
ON partes.id = partes_materiales.id_parte 

INNER JOIN clientes 
ON partes.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente 

WHERE partes.tecnico = 1
GROUP by partes.id
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado obtienes? Podrías compartir la estructura de tus tablas, así como un ejemplo del contenido que tienen. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta para agregar estos detalles. Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: ¿No es un typo?

Tú muestras esta estructura `ID, ID_PARTES, HORAS` sin embargo haces la referencia como `ID_PARTE` sin S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica de la consulta está fallando. Según entiendo lo que tu quieres es obtener la un resumen con la suma de lo que tienes en cada una de las tablas `partes_lineas` y `partes_materiales` por separado y, al hacer join antes de resumir, por cada fila que aparezca en una tabla se van a repetir todos los datos de la otra tabla.

De esta manera, el dato puede duplicarse, cuadruplicarse, etc.

Para lograr lo que buscas, puedes resumir primero cada una de las tablas y hacer el join para obtener el informe final hasta después de haber hecho este paso, algo en la línea de:

```
with
ResumenLineas as (
select id_parte, sum(horas) as horas
  from partes_lineas
 group by id_parte
)
,
ResumenMateriales as (
select id_parte, sum(pv_mat) as materiales
  from partes_materiales
 group by id_parte
)
select   partes.id
       , partes.fecha
       , clientes.nombre
       , partes.problema
       , ResumenLineas.horas
       , ResumenMateriales.materiales
       , partes.estado 
  from partes 
       LEFT JOIN ResumenLineas ON partes.id = ResumenLineas.id_parte 
       LEFT JOIN ResumenMateriales ON partes.id = ResumenMateriales.id_parte 
       INNER JOIN clientes ON partes.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente 
 WHERE partes.tecnico = 1
```

Si trabajas con versiones viejas de mySQL que no soportan CTE's, entonces puedes utilizar sub-consultas en el from, por ejemplo:

```
select   partes.id
       , partes.fecha
       , clientes.nombre
       , partes.problema
       , ResumenLineas.horas
       , ResumenMateriales.materiales
       , partes.estado
  from partes
       LEFT JOIN (select id_parte, sum(horas) as horas from partes_lineas group by id_parte)ResumenLineas ON partes.id = ResumenLineas.id_parte
       LEFT JOIN (select id_parte, sum(pv_mat) as materiales from partes_materiales group by id_parte) ON partes.id = ResumenMateriales.id_parte
       INNER JOIN clientes ON partes.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente
 WHERE partes.tecnico = 1
```

Como he dicho antes, lo que hago es resumir primero la información de cada tabla, para obtener la sumatoria por cada id_parte y, hasta entonces, hago el join de ambos resúmenes y el resto de tablas, ya sin aplicar ningún agrupamiento, pues el resumen me va a devolver una sola fila por cada parte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de gran ayuda.